# VS 2015 Community Installation Fails

Tags: visual-studio

I tried to install VS 2015 Community (free) on two different computers (both Windows 7 Professional).  And the installation fails on both.  The error message says:

```
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Developer Pack.
Incorrect function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to install

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Developer Pack first

Can be found here and hit download button compatible with the latest windows 10 system

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978

Then try and re install VS 2015 Community it should work

As had this problem before when I installed 2013 but putting the .net framework on before cured it and VS 2013 installed with no problems

Comment: Thank you for your message and suggestion.

Comment: No worries let me know what happens

Comment: It is astonishing. I was looking at the URL you suggested earlier today and decided to proceed later. Now when I go to this URL, I get MS message "We are sorry, the page requested cannot be found"

Comment: That is strange just tried it and it loads fine not sure what's the problem there or it could be actually the site was down when you tried it

Comment: rcollcott, thank you so much. The link and installation of .net 4.6.1 development pack solved the problem.